# VM stopped working - The content ID of the parent virtual disk does not match the corresponding parent content ID in the child

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have a virtual machine on VMware workstation, that stopped working after I tried to mount the vmdk file to a virtual disk with imDisk tools, the filesystem was not recognized and I accidentally clicked "format"

Here are all the important files of the VM.

If some files appears to be missing its because I deleted some snapshots from inside vmware workstation (without problems).

```
Kali-000001.vmdk
Kali-000002.vmdk
Kali-000004.vmdk
Kali-000005.vmdk
Kali-000006.vmdk
Kali-000007.vmdk
Kali-000008.vmdk
Kali-000009.vmdk
Kali-000013.vmdk
Kali-000015.vmdk

Kali.vmdk
```

I checked all the files and everything seems to be ok, the CIDs are linked... but in the logs i can see

```
vmx Power on failure messages: The parent virtual disk has been modified since the child was created. The content ID of the parent virtual disk does not match the corresponding parent content ID in the child

vmx Cannot open the disk '/mnt/ntsf1/Kali/Kali-000007.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.
```

So apparently the probleme is in Kali-000007.vmdk?

And I noticed a difference between this file and the others.

At the end of the other files there is a line similar to this:

```
ddb.longContentID = "df9ababd38b7f9eba8a16b9d5ec188dc"
```

But it is not present in Kali-000007.vmdk

Additional information:

Here is the content of all the files

**Kali.vmdk**

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
encoding="windows-1252"
CID=0ffb76bb
parentCID=ffffffff
createType="twoGbMaxExtentSparse"

# Extent description
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s001.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s002.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s003.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s004.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s005.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s006.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s007.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s008.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s009.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s010.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s011.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s012.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s013.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s014.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s015.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s016.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s017.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s018.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s019.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s020.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s021.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s022.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s023.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s024.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-s025.vmdk"
RW 1638400 SPARSE "Kali-s026.vmdk"

# The Disk Data Base
#DDB
ddb.adapterType = "lsilogic"
ddb.geometry.cylinders = "13054"
ddb.geometry.heads = "255"
ddb.geometry.sectors = "63"
ddb.longContentID = "db020a00fa554c0d3e2a4b5a305904a1"
ddb.toolsInstallType = "4"
ddb.toolsVersion = "11360"
ddb.uuid = "60 00 C2 99 5c d7 11 b4-f9 ff f2 bb 95 20 d7 44"
ddb.virtualHWVersion = "18"
```

**Kali-000001.vmdk**

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
encoding="windows-1252"
CID=5ec188dc
parentCID=0ffb76bb
createType="twoGbMaxExtentSparse"
parentFileNameHint="Kali-000004.vmdk"
# Extent description
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s001.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s002.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s003.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s004.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s005.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s006.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s007.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s008.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s009.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s010.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s011.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s012.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s013.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s014.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s015.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s016.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s017.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s018.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s019.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s020.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s021.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s022.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s023.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s024.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s025.vmdk"
RW 1638400 SPARSE "Kali-000001-s026.vmdk"

# The Disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.longContentID = "df9ababd38b7f9eba8a16b9d5ec188dc"
```

**Kali-000002.vmdk**

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
encoding="windows-1252"
CID=875f140a
parentCID=5ec188dc
createType="twoGbMaxExtentSparse"
parentFileNameHint="Kali.vmdk"
# Extent description
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s001.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s002.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s003.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s004.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s005.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s006.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s007.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s008.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s009.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s010.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s011.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s012.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s013.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s014.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s015.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s016.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s017.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s018.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s019.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s020.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s021.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s022.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s023.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s024.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s025.vmdk"
RW 1638400 SPARSE "Kali-000002-s026.vmdk"

# The Disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.longContentID = "dc197ca4a18d915556a7266f875f140a"
```

**Kali-000004.vmdk**

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
encoding="windows-1252"
CID=110b720e
parentCID=875f140a
createType="twoGbMaxExtentSparse"
parentFileNameHint="Kali-000002.vmdk"
# Extent description
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s001.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s002.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s003.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s004.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s005.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s006.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s007.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s008.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s009.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s010.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s011.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s012.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s013.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s014.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s015.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s016.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s017.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s018.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s019.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s020.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s021.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s022.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s023.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s024.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s025.vmdk"
RW 1638400 SPARSE "Kali-000004-s026.vmdk"

# The Disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.longContentID = "afec68a7173019d0d0556dc1110b720e"
```

**Kali-000005.vmdk**

```
version=1
encoding="windows-1252"
CID=979de4b8
parentCID=110b720e
createType="twoGbMaxExtentSparse"
parentFileNameHint="Kali-000009.vmdk"
# Extent description
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s001.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s002.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s003.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s004.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s005.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s006.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s007.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s008.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s009.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s010.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s011.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s012.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s013.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s014.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s015.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s016.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s017.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s018.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s019.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s020.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s021.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s022.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s023.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s024.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s025.vmdk"
RW 1638400 SPARSE "Kali-000005-s026.vmdk"

# The Disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.longContentID = "cf3d55ea869f9ab90953ecd6979de4b8"
```

**Kali-000006.vmdk**

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
encoding="windows-1252"
CID=dbc1ffaf
parentCID=979de4b8
createType="twoGbMaxExtentSparse"
parentFileNameHint="Kali-000015.vmdk"
# Extent description
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s001.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s002.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s003.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s004.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s005.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s006.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s007.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s008.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s009.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s010.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s011.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s012.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s013.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s014.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s015.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s016.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s017.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s018.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s019.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s020.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s021.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s022.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s023.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s024.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s025.vmdk"
RW 1638400 SPARSE "Kali-000006-s026.vmdk"

# The Disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.longContentID = "d1c0d5be8290d718b748480adbc1ffaf"
```

**Kali-000007.vmdk**

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
encoding="windows-1252"
CID=875f140a
parentCID=dbc1ffaf
createType="twoGbMaxExtentSparse"
parentFileNameHint="Kali-000002.vmdk"
# Extent description
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s001.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s002.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s003.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s004.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s005.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s006.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s007.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s008.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s009.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s010.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s011.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s012.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s013.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s014.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s015.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s016.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s017.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s018.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s019.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s020.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s021.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s022.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s023.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s024.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s025.vmdk"
RW 1638400 SPARSE "Kali-000007-s026.vmdk"

# The Disk Data Base 
#DDB

## POSSIBLE PROBLEME HERE
# Missing line ? -> ddb.longContentID = "xxx"
```

**Kali-000008.vmdk**

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
encoding="windows-1252"
CID=f2c46ee4
parentCID=875f140a
createType="twoGbMaxExtentSparse"
parentFileNameHint="Kali-000013.vmdk"
# Extent description
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s001.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s002.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s003.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s004.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s005.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s006.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s007.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s008.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s009.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s010.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s011.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s012.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s013.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s014.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s015.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s016.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s017.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s018.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s019.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s020.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s021.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s022.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s023.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s024.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s025.vmdk"
RW 1638400 SPARSE "Kali-000008-s026.vmdk"

# The Disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.longContentID = "9ed69ba48b08bfaabdae953cf2c46ee4"
```

**Kali-000009.vmdk**

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
encoding="windows-1252"
CID=aa6bb9b6
parentCID=f2c46ee4
createType="twoGbMaxExtentSparse"
parentFileNameHint="Kali-000001.vmdk"
# Extent description
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s001.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s002.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s003.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s004.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s005.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s006.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s007.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s008.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s009.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s010.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s011.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s012.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s013.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s014.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s015.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s016.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s017.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s018.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s019.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s020.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s021.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s022.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s023.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s024.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s025.vmdk"
RW 1638400 SPARSE "Kali-000009-s026.vmdk"

# The Disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.longContentID = "4c0da7737fa6d6e425b3c405aa6bb9b6"
```

**Kali-000013.vmdk**

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
encoding="windows-1252"
CID=bb8be03a
parentCID=aa6bb9b6
createType="twoGbMaxExtentSparse"
parentFileNameHint="Kali-000005.vmdk"
# Extent description
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s001.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s002.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s003.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s004.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s005.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s006.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s007.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s008.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s009.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s010.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s011.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s012.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s013.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s014.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s015.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s016.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s017.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s018.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s019.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s020.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s021.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s022.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s023.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s024.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s025.vmdk"
RW 1638400 SPARSE "Kali-000013-s026.vmdk"

# The Disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.longContentID = "b83ba677f61b00fddf973408bb8be03a"
```

**Kali-000015.vmdk**

```
version=1
encoding="windows-1252"
CID=9d2a0652
parentCID=bb8be03a
createType="twoGbMaxExtentSparse"
parentFileNameHint="Kali-000008.vmdk"
# Extent description
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s001.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s002.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s003.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s004.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s005.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s006.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s007.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s008.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s009.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s010.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s011.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s012.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s013.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s014.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s015.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s016.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s017.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s018.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s019.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s020.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s021.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s022.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s023.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s024.vmdk"
RW 8323072 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s025.vmdk"
RW 1638400 SPARSE "Kali-000015-s026.vmdk"

# The Disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.longContentID = "ca8e71939389b8cbcb4614f49d2a0652"
```

And here is the full `vmware.log`: https://pastebin.com/L04NeaBj

Answer (score 0):

> i have a virtual machine on vmware workstation, that stopped working
> after i tried to mount the vmdk file to a virtual disk with imDisk
> tools, the filesystem was not recognised and i accidentally clicked
> "format"

That has damaged the particular segment. Since you click (accidentally) on Format, the segment is not likely recoverable.

Best approach is to make a new virtual machine.

Unless you have a reason to use multiple segments, I find it best to have just one VMDK file instead of multiple files.

Also VMware Snapshots are not backups and need to be combined or deleted in the VMware Snapshot Manager. The Snapshot you have may not be consistent because of the damaged segment.

(Posted from my Kali machine in VMware Workstation 16 on a Windows 10 host).

Answer (score 0):

> Here are all the important files of the VM.
>
> If some files appears to be missing its because I deleted some snapshots from inside vmware workstation (without problems).

If the files you listed are really all of your `.vmdk` files, then there are *many* files that are missing.

Each of the files named `Kali-######.vmdk` is a *delta disk*, which stores the set of changes written to the virtual disk from the parent.  You're using split disks, so each of those files is backed by a number of *disk extents*, which are the `Kali-######-s######.vmdk` files.  If you deleted those files, you've deleted all of your data.

> vmx Power on failure messages: The parent virtual disk has been modified since the child was created. The content ID of the parent virtual disk does not match the corresponding parent content ID in the child
>
> vmx Cannot open the disk '/mnt/ntsf1/Kali/Kali-000007.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.

You accidentally modified one of the parent virtual disks in your chain of delta disks, and that's bad because that invalidates all of delta disks  that depend on it.  If you mounted and wrote to one of the `Kali-######.vmdk` files, then you might have a snapshot that does not depend on that `.vmdk` file and that therefore would be valid.  I would try to restore progressively older snapshots to see if any of them work, and then you could recover *some* of your data.

If you mounted and accidentally wrote to the *base disk* (`Kali.vmdk`), then unfortunately, all of your snapshots will be invalid and unusable.